# jquery using filter to separate elements and act on them differently

Tags: jquery

I have a `.infodiv` class with say 4 elements.  I want to filter out 1 div by id and `fadeToggle` it, and `fadeOut` the others.

My code now is

```
$(".infodiv").filter('#'+id+"div").fadeToggle("slow").fadeOut("slow");
```

this now filters and acts correctly on my filter, but then the following fadeout command would also act on the filtered element.

What extra commands/syntax in the chain is needed so that the fadeout only acts on the other 3 elements.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revert to the previous set in the chain if you use [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/).

```
$(".infodiv").filter('#'+id+"div").fadeToggle("slow").end().fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, it works, but it conflicts with another process in my code that I did not outline here, so I decided to go with .not